# Using Spark on an Iterative Process

Tags: python, apache-spark

I'm new to Spark and am trying to understand the best way to set up iterative processes to run in parallel.

For example, if I have a DataFrame and the [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) (which says, given a function that returns `3n+1` if n is odd and `n/2` if n is even, if we repeatedly run this function, it will always eventually return 1) and I want to determine how many iterations it takes to return 1 -- I can easily write this iteratively (as that's how it's defined) like

```
nums = [(x, 0) for x in range(1, 5)]
schema = ['num', 'iters']
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=nums, schema=schema)
while True:
    checker = df.filter(F.col('num') != 1)
    if (checker.count() == 0):
        break

    df = df.withColumn('num', 
                F.when(
                    F.col('num') == 1,
                    F.col('num')
                )
                .otherwise(
                    F.when(F.col('num') % F.lit(2) != 0, 
                        F.col('num') * F.lit(3) + F.lit(1)
                    )
                    .otherwise(
                        F.col('num') / F.lit(2)
                    )
                )
    )
    df = df.withColumn('iters',
                F.when(F.col('num') != 1.0, F.col('iters') + F.lit(1))
                .otherwise(F.col('iters'))
    )

df.show()
```

Note: I know that you can do this stuff recursively and do a better job with all of this. I'm just using this as an example of iterative processes in Spark.

But this is really ugly and doesn't optimize on Spark. I know that loops are an antipattern in Spark -- but I'm not sure how else one goes about doing this.

Comment: unfortunately, it seems you will need to solve the Collatz Conjecture itself to determine the iteration length

Comment: I'm just trying to set up a dummy example to explain the problem I'm trying to solve which is: how can you best do iterative processes in spark?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that using explicit loops may be not very efficient way to implement iterative processes in Spark.

I think you can use **pyspark.sql.functions** and **udf** to define the transformations in a more functional manner.

Assuming that I understood your use case, The idea is to repeatedly apply the transformation until all the numbers in the DataFrame reach the value 1. Here's an approach:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# Initialize Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("CollatzConjecture").getOrCreate()

# Define a UDF (User-Defined Function) for the Collatz transformation
def collatz_transform(num):
    return num * 3 + 1 if num % 2 != 0 else num // 2

# Register the UDF
collatz_udf = F.udf(collatz_transform)

# Create the initial DataFrame
nums = [(x, 0) for x in range(1, 5)]
schema = ['num', 'iters']
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=nums, schema=schema)

# Define a function to apply the Collatz transformation until all numbers reach 1
def collatz_iteration(df):
    return df.withColumn('num', F.when(F.col('num') == 1, F.col('num')).otherwise(collatz_udf(F.col('num')))) \
             .withColumn('iters', F.col('iters') + F.lit(1))

# Iterate until all numbers reach 1
while df.filter(F.col('num') != 1).count() > 0:
    df = collatz_iteration(df)

df.show()
```

Tell me if this matches your needs.

Comment: This is very helpful! Thank you very much! I am confused about why the performance of this `udf` would be better than the performance that I had. Isn't the loop the main culprit in why this isn't so performant?